# Have to refresh page for jplayer to play another file

Tags: refresh, jplayer

I have multiple links on one page that I'd like to be able to click on and play through a single JPlayer. The files are coming from amazon s3. Currently it will play the first one you click on fine but clicking on the other links won't do anything without reloading the page. Heres the JS I'm working with.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.html5').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    m4a: url
                });
            },
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "m4a"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setMedia method to set the new url

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var someurlonload='setyoururl.mp4'
   $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a: someurlonload
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "m4a"
    });

    $('a.html5').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {

              m4a: url

          }).jPlayer("play");
    return false;
    });
});
```